# This is regarding a simple code in python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I have two tables here

```
 Reg_No     Name  Marks Grade  Sub1  Sub2
     1  Sanjana    100    A1  60.0   NaN
     2    Alfaz     70     A   NaN  65.0
     3     Ritu     50     B  30.0   NaN
     4    Priya     60     A   NaN  40.0

        Sub1  Sub2
IA      0.50  0.40
OA      0.50  0.60
Others  0.25  0.25
```

The first table contains `marks`,`sub1` and `sub2` and the second table contains `IA`, `OA`, `Others` as rows based on the subjects.

I need to split the column `Marks` of the first table based on the second table into 3 new columns. The first column is the `IA` column, if its `sub1` in the first table, it should split based on the `sub1` column of second table

example:

```
IA = table1.marks*table2(IA)(sub1)
```

i.e `100*0.50`

This should be my output

```
Reg_No  Name    Marks   Grade   Sub 1   Sub 2   IA_ OA_ Others_
1   Sanjana       100    A1     60              50  50  25
2   Alfaz         100    A              65      40  60  25
3   Ritu          100    B      30              50  50  25
4   Priya         100    A              40      40  60  25
```

Please tell me how to code for this

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not image) in question (not in comment).

Comment: show expected result - also as text.

Comment: updated please check

Comment: not updated - I still see only images, not text. And I done see any code. My python can't use data from image.

Comment: i dont have the code, data is updated

Comment: You should show what have you tried and where did it fail, so we can help you navigate. SO is not a coding service, you have to show your own effort.

Answer (score 0):

I get every row from second `DataFrame` and use it with `apply()` to create new column in first `DataFrame`

```
import pandas as pd
import io

text = '''Marks  Sub1  Sub2
100    60.0  NaN
70     NaN   65.0
50     30.0  NaN
60     NaN   40.0'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

text = '''Sub1  Sub2
IA      0.50  0.40
OA      0.50  0.60
Others  0.25  0.25'''
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), sep='\s+')

for row in df2.itertuples():
    name, sub1, sub2 = row  
    df1[name] = df1.apply(lambda x: (x['Marks']*sub2) if pd.isna(x['Sub1']) else (x['Marks']*sub1), axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Result:

```
   Marks  Sub1  Sub2    IA    OA  Others
0    100  60.0   NaN  50.0  50.0    25.0
1     70   NaN  65.0  28.0  42.0    17.5
2     50  30.0   NaN  25.0  25.0    12.5
3     60   NaN  40.0  24.0  36.0    15.0
```